# Reproducing the border of a UITextField

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, calayer

I want to fade in the border for a UITextField, so am recreating it myself in a UIView, using its layer:

```
    borderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textfield.frame.size.width, textfield.frame.size.height)];
    [borderView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [borderView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [borderView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [borderView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
    [borderView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [borderView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];
    [borderView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
    borderView.alpha = 0.0;
```

I then add it to the UITextField directly:

```
    [textField addSubview: borderView];
    [textField sendSubviewToBack: borderView];
```

However, despite the sendSubviewToBack: call, the text field refuses to become first responder when it is touched.

This worked fine when I was adding an ImageView as a sibling view instead of a UIView.

How can I make the textfield receive input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
borderView.userInteraction = NO;
```

Checked it in my sim 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new view to the text field, just modify the text field's own layer:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textField.layer.borderWidth = 1;
textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
// etc...
```

Comment: I need to use a separate view so that I can animate it.